# Concurrent Update

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, concurrency

I'm building an application that deals with a *Wallet*. I have *cash-in* and *cash-out*s of this wallet.
And I have a problem when an update occurs to + or - of this wallet.
Look the scenario:

A user makes a cash-in and the system retrieves the *balance* of this wallet like this:

```
select * from Wallet where idUser = x;
```

So this query above returns the wallet, and * get the 'balance' column and do like this

```
wallet.balance += amount;
```

After this I will make the update to insert the new 'balance' of this wallet and do this

```
update Wallet set balance = balanceVar where idWallet = x;
```

Until here everything looks fine but when we deal with concurrent cash in and cash outs what's the better scenario in this case.
Put this in a queue?
Lock the table while doing the update?
This is the first time I deal with a system like that and I'm really confused about what to do.

Comment: Use a single query, `UPDATE Wallet SET balance = balance + 10 WHERE idwallet = x` You dont need to get the wallet to do that, you are just adding OR subtracting a value from the balance

Comment: MySQL will do the locking, in reality only one thing happens at a time to you DB

Comment: But in this case if a update occurred concurrent the value of balance can be inconsistent.

Comment: No because you dont first fetch the balance, all you do is add or subtract to/from it all in one hit

Comment: Yeah is just that, but thinking in large scale maybe it occurs.. imagine millions of request doing this... in one time maybe the balance it will be wrong, i guess...

Comment: See comment 2, mysql is built to cope with this

Comment: Ok.. So.. how?  The mysql enqueue the queries and do one by one? If i have more than one connection, even so the mysql will do one by one?

Answer (score 2):

Your `SELECT` then `UPDATE` scheme leads directly to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) where two processes can SELECT the same data, and then perform the same update, leading to an inconsistency where two updates occur, but only one is recorded.

The way to avoid this is to use an atomic operation (i.e. one that can't be divided).

In your case you should simply update the wallet directly:

```
update Wallet set balance = balance+10 where idWallet = 'x';
```

This update will complete in its entirety before another process can perform another update.

You can go further with this idea. For withdrawals you could update the wallet only if the balance is greater than or equal to the withdrawal:

```
update Wallet set balance = balance-10 where idWallet = 'x' and balance >= 10;
```

You can test `ROW_COUNT()` to see if the operation succeeded. PHP provides `mysqli_affected_rows()` or `PDOStatement::rowCount()` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing in these cases is to use **transactions** to guarantee the integrity of the information, in this way the manager will take care of the possible conflicts that arise when manipulating the information

Comment: Using transactions maybe i will perform a deadlock no? Because if 2 things try to do the same thing at the same moment..